# Tab Host Image Hover not working Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm setting a image hover in my Tab Host using xml file. But its not working for Me. Please take a look at my codes below to see if I forgotten something or if there is something wrong in my codes.

Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
        songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab

    }

}
```

My XML file for Hover

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photohover"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo" />

</selector>
```

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working for you?

Comment: it's not changing. No design at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. I just change  getResources() to context.getResources() and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i checked your code it is working fine. I don't know what's your problem. Please check this link. It will helps you to understand the Tabwidget concept. http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/tabwidget-in-android-advance.html

Let me know still you are facing a problem with tabwiget, with clear information.

Comment: I understand how tab host works. I just didn't know why does my Hover codes not work.

Comment: can i know how you implement your photohover and photo in drawable folder?

Comment: I just paste the photo @ my drawable-hdpi and I implemented it like what I post above

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_pressed"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" />
    <!-- unselected state (default) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```